# Apache Beam returns "Input values must not be mutated in any way." when using local direct runner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I wrote an Apache Beam DoFn

```
static class FillLocation extends DoFn<TrackingRequest, TrackingRequest> {
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {    
            TrackingRequest rq = c.element();
            rq.location = getLocationFromIP(rq.IP);         
            c.output(rq);
        }
}
```

And it gave me this error when testing it locally
 PTransform .. illegaly mutated value .. of class.....

```
 Input values must not be mutated in any way.
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.ImmutabilityEnforcementFactory$ImmutabilityCheckingEnforcement.verifyUnmodified(ImmutabilityEnforcementFactory.java:96)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.ImmutabilityEnforcementFactory$ImmutabilityCheckingEnforcement.afterElement(ImmutabilityEnforcementFactory.java:71)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.TransformExecutor.processElements(TransformExecutor.java:149)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.TransformExecutor.run(TransformExecutor.java:107)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your function modified the location field of the input TrackingRequest element. This is not allowed by the Dataflow.

The [doc](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/DoFn) says:

> The current element of the input PCollection is returned by c.element(). It should be considered immutable. The Dataflow runtime will not mutate the element, so it is safe to cache, etc. The element should not be mutated by any of the DoFn methods, because it may be cached elsewhere, retained by the Dataflow runtime, or used in other unspecified ways.

You can create a copy of the input element, modify the field, and send the copy out as output.

Comment: OK. but why it is not giving error when using testing it on Google Cloud?

Comment: It is somewhat expensive to detect when you have mutated an element. Thus, it is the testing `DirectRunner` that checks this, to catch errors in your pipeline early. If you perform mutations like this on Google Cloud Dataflow, you may actually just get incorrect results at random!

Comment: You may also be interested in following https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1164